# Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Prove that $\det(A^T A)\geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Consider $A^{T}A$. Is $\det(A^T A)\geq 0?$ Either prove your answer or give an explicit counterexample.

I've been trying to figure out the soultion to this for awhile, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming these are matrices over the reals, the answer is yes, because $A^T A$ is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 3):

$\det(A^TA)=\det(A^T)\det(A)=\det(A)^2$.

To see $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$ you can use the definition in terms of the permutations and see they are exactly the same.